# How would someone in the 16th century react if a Wal-Mart flew down from the sky?

Tags: alternate-history

I have been throwing around the idea what would happen if on earth in the 16th century something similar happened like in *The Wizard of Oz* but instead of a house a Wal-mart got sucked into the tornado or something that took the building there (in the middle of a village housing 18 people, and 13 have a the flu). And instead of Dorothy, I say it would be 24 adults and 5 kids in the Wal-mart.

How would the people in the village and inside the Wal-mart react? Would there be a large breakthrough in science and design, or would the villagers lose their heads? What would the people in Wal-mart have to face at this time, sicknesses, or wars, anything else?

Comment: How would **you** react if a Wal-Mart flew down from the sky? That is not something that happens everyday, even in the 21st century. Of course, maybe to people in the 1600 century (which would be between the years 159.901 and 160.000) it is not a big deal, due to their advanced technology.

Answer (score 7):

Well, from what I've read, villages of that era were not very large in size. Half a mile across, maybe. So, pretty much all 18 of those people will be buried under 150000 square feet of supercenter (plus parking lot and perhaps an 18 wheeler or two at the back unloading).

If any of the three relatively healthy inhabitants happened to be looking up in the seconds before the crash, I'm sure the reaction would be quite intelligible to those moderns barreling downwards:

**"Oh, odsbod...!"**

Comment: You are an evil minded person. But in your defence, that's exactly what I thought would happen. However, the expletives uttered by the soon to be expired villagers wouldn't be excremental. At that rime rude words were usually based on religion. Swear words are based on taboos. 16th century villagers lived closer to their waste than we do. Defecation & urination only became taboo after we cleaned up our act in the 19th century with improved plumbing & hygiene.

Comment: By Zadook's bodlikins, that is an excellent point! And one deserving of historically accurate rectification. So, "oh, sh...!" might perhaps be replaced...

Comment: I beseech you from the bowels of Christ to think of phrases praising His Name and Holy Attributes. "In Jesu's Name", "God's Body" (which does become odds bodikin in later years IIRC) and similar. Your rectification catches the flavour of the recquisite perjoratives. [The first ten words of this comment are a quotation from a speech by Oliver Cromwell to give a sense of this type of language.]

Comment: Shocking! All these answers and comments and not one reference to ruby slippers:(

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I suspect there would be no breakthrough. Flu might well be a cause of serious issues between the ages as neither party would have immunity against the strains present in the other time era.

The likely reaction would be terror followed by curiosity then plundering of food. I doubt the inhabitants from the 16th century would be able to make sense of what happened at all and this would not be helped by the fact that most if not all of the village inhabitants would be illiterate. No doubt eventually news would spread to the local lords in the area. It is hard to be certain what would happen eventually, but I think they would probably burn down the store thinking it was some sort of witchcraft.

Comment: Eventually someone is going to figure out how that Remmington 870 works...

Answer (score 1):

The people in Walmart may be treated with suspicion. They may end up barricaded in the store, living on the stores of food within to keep the villagers from trying to take it. They might not leave anyway to avoid the various types of disease they have no immunity to.

If that scenario didn't occur, I don't think there would be a huge breakthrough in technology. Things like TV, cell phones, and computers won't really work if there is no power source. Any battery powered technology would eventually stop working once batteries ran out.

Not to mention that just because there are things like television and radio doesn't mean the everyday layman would be able to teach someone how they work. Additionally, a lack of widespread communication would likely limit the spread of new knowledge.